# Why is my constructor not working?

Tags: java, class

I'm struggling with my my class constructor for a Java class I'm taking. Essentially, we're creating a Trapezoid class that takes in three double variables as arguments. Here is what my class-wide variables and constructor looks like:

```
public class Trapezoid 
{

 double height;
 double longer;
 double shorter; 

public Trapezoid(double heightofTrapezoid, double longerSide, double shorterSide)
{
    heightofTrapezoid = height;
    longerSide = longer;
    shorterSide = shorter;
}
```

However, when I try to create a Trapezoid object in my driver class, and print out the values, It's returning 0's for each variable. Here is my driver class:

```
public class TrapezoidApp
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Arbitrary test values
        final double height = 10.0;
        final double longer = 5.5;
        final double shorter = 7.25;

        // Calculated offline from the above test values, used to verify code
        final double area = 63.75;

        // Instantiate a trapezoid object so that we can test it
        Trapezoid t = new Trapezoid(height, longer, shorter);
        double calculatedArea = t.getArea();

        // Our "test" is to display the received values next to the expected
        // values and verify that they match visually
        System.out.println("All of the following numbers should match:");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("       Expected  Received");
        System.out.println("       --------  --------");
        System.out.printf("Height:%8.2f  %8.2f\n", height, t.getHeight());
        System.out.printf("  Long:%8.2f  %8.2f\n", longer, t.getLongerSide());
        System.out.printf(" Short:%8.2f  %8.2f\n", shorter, t.getShorterSide());
        System.out.printf("  Area:%8.2f  %8.2f\n", area, t.getArea());
    }
}
```

Could I get some help with this? Thanks so much.

Comment: Have you tried hooking up a debugger? And what do your getHeight, getLongerSide, getShorterSide methods look like?

Answer (score 8):

Assignment is right to left.

This

```
heightofTrapezoid = height;
```

should be

```
height = heightofTrapezoid;
```

Same for the other fields.

Comment: Thank you so much. Worked perfectly. I'll chalk this one up to a case of the Mondays and try not to be embarrassed by it.

Answer (score 1):

```
 double height;
 double longer;
 double shorter; 

public Trapezoid(double heightofTrapezoid, double longerSide, double shorterSide)
{
    height = heightofTrapezoid;
    longer = longerSide;
    shorter = shorterSide;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, the problem is with assignments and I would suggest you learn to use the **this** keyword inside your constructor.

```
 public Trapezoid(double heightofTrapezoid, double longerSide, double shorterSide)
  {
     this.height = heightofTrapezoid;
     this.longer = longerSide;
     this.shorter = shorterSide;
  }
```